# Typescript: Creating a function where inputs are dependent on each other

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I need to make a function that parses a number of json strings into specified classes, before handing them over to an initializer function. To get an idea of my skill level, I have been using typescript for a few years, but I only started looking into conditional types yesterday because of this task. My attempt currently looks like this:

```
init<P extends any[]>(parsers: P, loadInstructions: (
 ...data: { [I in keyof P]: InstanceType<P[I]> }
) => Result): Result {
  ...
}
```

What it SHOULD do, is to take an arbibrary number of types in the "parsers" input, and then restrict the input for the loadInstructions function to match the types of the parsers array. There should be as little contraint as possible. I would prefer if the parsers array could just take any type.

An example of what I would like to end up with:

```
class A1{
   name: string;
}

class A2{
   address: string;
}

this.init(route, [A1, A1, A2], (a:A1, b:A1, c:A2) => {
    return new Result();
});
```

But this is not what is happening in reality.
The parser does allow me to write any types into the parsers array, and the a,b,c parameters in the loadInstructions function also gets a union of A1, and A2 inferred on them, i feel like I am slowing going in the right direction.

But my my remaining issues is that the browser infers a union of the types on the loadInstructions parameters, instead of the actual corresponding type from the array. The other problem, that I am less fuzzy about, is that loadInstructions is not restricted to a length equal to the parsers array. It would be nice if the amount of parameters for loadInstructions were forced to be equal to the length of the parsers array.

As it should always be, any other related wisdom nuggets are very welcome :)

I am running typescript 4.7

Thank you

Comment: Does `this.init([A1, A1, A2] as const, (a:A1, b:A1, c:A2) => {
  return new Result();
});` solve the problem for you? Note: init must take `init<P extends readonly any[]>` If not, what am I missing? See https://tsplay.dev/wO1Zlm

Comment: It creates two issues. First of all, a compiler error which might be causing the other issue: 
TS2345: Argument of type 'readonly [typeof A1, typeof A1, typeof A2]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'any[]'.   The type 'readonly [typeof A1, typeof A1, typeof A2]' is 'readonly' and cannot be assigned to the mutable type 'any[]'.

The second issue is that a,b and c are now inferred as any

Comment: have you applied <P extends **readonly** any[]> change mentioned in my first comment?

Comment: yes i have. I am still on typescript 4.7 if that might be the problem

Comment: Strange, I get no errors in TS playgrouund on 4.7.4: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/MYGwhgzhAEBKCmECuIAu0DeBfAUD0kMAggIwY7SUB2YAtvAFzQSoBOAllQObQC80AIhr0BAbhy584KNCIAmcpWhgAJitaIITFh259Bq9ZrES8eAGZIqwVOwD2VaJ3aoAPAAVo8AB6p4VFRgNVQcQAE9lKjCAbQBdAD4ACgAHMFYIeHSmdwAaaBA7VQBJKh0kG3tSpkSKADp6lTBUMCYMaGiip0cAa3gwu3Nod1imEpYwa3gAFTDk+A8OhOhcAEo+eLhEFFQVpgRkNEwKaGAHCDsQeFqCrkSAcjBHu5XxSg1UJFZHKngAd02DqhEi9TPgzuhUulMjB+NFSHl4bI5LFxDhnEC4SQEVikbFlDBTqVUHlEi1EQAjBiI4BUuRrXgbRTQd6fb5-AHbYHiLAvIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, this is what you're looking for.

```ts
function init<const P extends Readonly<Array<unknown>>>(parsers: P, loadInstructions: (
 ...data: { [I in keyof P]: P[I] extends abstract new (...args: any) => any ? InstanceType<P[I]> : P[I] }
) => any): any {
  //...
}

init(["A1", "A2", "A3"], (a,b,c) => {});
```

Here's a [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=7&ssc=41&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDMMoB4IIM5UQBUQFMAPKIsAE20QCUiBDShAGwE90BBAJ24Y-ABrMHADuYAHxSAFAAcG3bEUUAuAgBpELOEwCSYXNxDR4BtdIBQiAHS3KDKAzUBvRAG1dyJIKJs4wAgBdNXwPQOIyCmpEBgAjQwZoRDAiUURpW2sFAHNsNQYwNgBKRABeCRjCxAB+RH1cAogiABU2WSJ0UN1AipCwxABfCxLyyuL8qucrRAB6GcyLIYsUNGk3ACJOAEZ1zU2AJl3ETYBmdcDNaQZ1WPUIEYrnAaKAbiA) to the playground.

Mind that you'll need to use Typescript version `5.x.x` for this to work, due to [const type parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-0.html#const-type-parameters).

### Update

I got it to work for pre-`5.x.x` as well. Here's how -

```ts
type Cast<A, B> = A extends B ? A : B;

type Narrowable =
| string
| number
| bigint
| boolean;

type Narrow<A> = Cast<A,
| []
| (A extends Narrowable ? A : never)
| ({ [K in keyof A]: Narrow<A[K]> })
>;

function init<P extends Readonly<Array<unknown>>>(parsers: Narrow<P>, loadInstructions: (
  ...data: { [I in keyof P]: P[I] extends abstract new (...args: any) => any ? InstanceType<P[I]> : P[I] }
) => any): any {
  //...
}

init([new Date(), "A2", "A3"], (a, b, c) => { });
```

[link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghgZ2AHgIIBooCEB8UC8UqUEAHsBAHYAmC2UA-EVAFzYDcAUJ6JFAHJwATkID2AdzgAjADbR8nAD5QkQgJaUA5kqiUArgFspEITqlrNG4GdGi5cSlx7hogkRLR5C8JGnQ6AbQBdHQAKYjIKGjo3MUlZaCZiNkoIADcTAEowgG8oAIBpKA0oAGsIEFEAMyIgtliPVEKgvABfbJwnKr1KAGNgNVFKYso1FAAFEnIqWigAJQg4aiGZEDQRODWe0soJShwD0LBhBBMEeuE45HGcTBlRJYBJSlU9fsGXtlDOKCgAOgB1DgwDgbDyAUeIzKFWqUHGdThEKCUyis2kqjg-V0EHEUFCAL+wk05ygDhAmQIeDJjCgzyQDl6EAAKi5rki8GxxkioK1OBT8FTKOS2NScj8oAB6CUEzi8zgaMahAKpXEAEWBEFCmUwACJUAAmHW61AAZh1QUwoTgmCkmF6-LweXa7CAA) to the playground.

Found this awesome utility `Narrow` [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30680#issuecomment-752725353).

Comment: I had hoped for something that was strongly typed. "A1", "A2", "A3" are just strings aren't they?

Comment: That's just for the sake of showing how it'll be. It'll in fact ask for the exact same params as the elements of that array. Try the link that I provided to the playground. If you wish to, you can add more constraints for `P[I]` in the second line.

Comment: It works! in the playground. Unfortunately I am unable to upgrade to TS 5 at the moment. But i will try to mess around with the old "as const" and see

Comment: @MartinNielsen I think this should take care of your requirement for version 4.